# How does Oblex interact with non-humanoids?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Many of the things I am finding about Oblexes are how they behave when they are found by the average NPC or adventurer. What about if it is a non-humanoid or a magical being? Something that might have centuries worth of memory on hand?

We are going to assume in this scenario the Oblex has a significant chance to perform its eat memories at least once and potentially completely subdue the being. Does *eat memories* sample only surface memory? Are they able to go deeper? Any fun mutations that can occur?

Comment: Welcome to the stack nubbinz, take the [tour] when you have a moment. It isn’t clear to me what game you are playing, and we need to know that before we can help. Additionally, it isnt clear what exactly your question is. Is there something in particular about the rules your game uses for an Oblex that is unclear?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Probably for the best to leave a comment explaining how you came to the conclusion that this is a D&D 5e question.

Comment: I think it is safe to add the 5e tag here because: The Oblex is a new monster created by "Guest Designer" Nolan Whale. Whale was a Make-A-Wish recipient who asked to spend the day with the D&D team in 2017, during the production of Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes. Nolan spent the day working with the D&D and conceiving various new ideas for the upcoming book. During this time D&D was 5e.

Answer (score 4):

### It works the same for most creatures, but oblexes prefer intelligent prey

The oblex is described in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*, p. 217-2019. Its **Eat Memories** ability reads:

> The oblex targets **one creature** it can see within 5 feet of it. The target must succeed on a DC 15 Wisdom saving throw or take 18 (4d8) psychic damage and become memory drained until it finishes a short or long rest or until it benefits from the greater restoration or heal spell. **Constructs, oozes, plants, and undead succeed on the save automatically.**

So it can memory drain any creature except constructs, oozes, plants or undead. The ablility speaks about creatures, not about humanoids, so it can drain non-humanoids. There is no age limitation, it can drain very old beings.

The lore entry of the Oblex says:

> **Memory Eaters**. Oblexes feed on thoughts and memories. The sharper the mind, the better the meal, so oblexes **hunt obviously intelligent targets such as wizards and other spellcasters**.

So while oblexes could attack less intelligent creatures like beasts, they focus on intelligent targets. This could include highly intelligent non-humanoids, such as sphinxes, adult dragons, celestials, and fiends.

The lore continues:

> An oblex devours memories not only to sustain its existence, but also to spawn new oblexes. Each time it **fully drains the memories of a victim**, it gains the creature's personality-now twisted by the oblex's foul nature.

The oblex does not only drain surface memories. Not only are they "able to go deeper", they are able to **fully drain** all the memories the vicitim has.

The Sulfurous Impersonation feature of the oblex states:

> the oblex can extrude a piece of itself that assumes the appearance of one **Medium or smaller** creature whose memories it has stolen. This simulacrum appears, feels, and sounds **exactly like the creature it impersonates**, though it smells faintly of sulfur.

No mutations occur. The simulacrums that are created appear, feel and sound **exactly like** the creatures they impersonate.

Note that most highly intelligent non-humanoids such as sphinxes, adult dragons, and many celestials and fiends mentioned above are Large or larger, so while the oblex could drain their memories (if it survives the encounter), it could not form simulacra from them, as the simulacrum can only be Medium-sized or smaller.

There are not that many non-humanoid monsters elegible that are Medium or smaller and highly intelligent (16 or more Intelligence) for the oblex to create simulacra from. If you are looking for interesting options with Challenge Ratings up to 10 (comparable to an Elder Oblex), they include the Couatl, Dybukk, Neogi Master, Night Hag,  Mind Flayer, Hydroloth, Deva and various Eldarin.

Comment: When answering a question the doesn’t specify the game system, you need to specify the game system in your answer. Notably, *I have no idea where you’re getting any of these quotes from*, because you haven’t said where they’re from, and neither the question nor your answer tells us what game you’re talking about.

Comment: (You can find our guidance for handling under specified questions [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11722/what-should-i-do-when-a-question-does-not-specify-the-game-system-being-used).)

Comment: Ah, neat find. Just leave a comment on the question explaining the tag addition and we’re good to go.

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine, but could still be improved be pointing to the sourcebook (MToF?). You also have a lonely “**” missing its partner in the last quote. And yeah, the downvote was for answering a question that gave no game or sourcebook with an answer that gave no game or sourcebook.

Comment: I've used once an Oblex that was able to create a Simulacra of a dragon, having fed on it ages ago. The two beings ended up merged somewhat, and I used it as the BBEG of my campaign - Mol'dyas, The Putrid - the very first "Ooze Dragon" of that world. It was a fun game.